# Change background of input based on saved data in database inside loop

Tags: php, database, for-loop, pdo

I have a loop from `1` to `100` as value of `input`. I want to show all saved data from the database which will change the background of the input. I use `bootstrap` button class to change the color of the background.

In this following, I'm just able to show the last or the first (`ASC`/`DESC`) but not all of them. Here, I have 2 records (number 1 and 3).

```
    <?php
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 100; $x++) {
        $num = sprintf("%02d", $x);
        //kjghghj
        $recNo = $_GET['sub'];
        $qUsr = "SELECT * FROM pengerjaan_gratis WHERE kodeuser = '".$recNo."' LIMIT 100";
        $sUsr = $dbkdw->prepare($qUsr);
        $sUsr->execute();
        while ($rowUsr = $sUsr->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $kiduser = $rowUsr['id'];
            $kodeuser = $rowUsr['kodeuser'];
            $nomor_soal = $rowUsr['nomorsoal'];
            $jawaban = $rowUsr['jawaban'];
            $primary = 'btn-primary';
            $default = 'btn-default';
            }
            ?>
            <!--tombol-->
            <input type="submit" id="btn_nomor" name="btn_nomor" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="btn 
            <?php
            if ($nomor_soal == $x){
                echo $primary;
                }
            else{
                echo $default;
                }
            ?>
            " value="<?php echo $num; ?>"/>
            <?php 
            }
        ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, finally I find the answer after attempting. I forgot to add `$x` in query, as follow:

```
$qUsr = "SELECT * FROM pengerjaan_gratis
WHERE kodeuser = '".$recNo."' AND nomorsoal = '".$x."' LIMIT 100";
```

Here's the full correction and the screenshot where the two rows are shown in `btn-primary` (as saved data in the database)

```
<?php
            //kjghghj
            $recNo = $_GET['sub'];
            for ($x = 1; $x <= 100; $x++) {
                $num = sprintf("%02d", $x);
                //cari
                $qUsr = "SELECT * FROM pengerjaan_gratis 
WHERE kodeuser = '".$recNo."' AND nomorsoal = '".$x."' LIMIT 100";
                $sUsr = $dbkdw->prepare($qUsr);
                $sUsr->execute();
                while ($rowUsr = $sUsr->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    $iduser = $rowUsr['id'];
                    $kodeuser = $rowUsr['kodeuser'];
                    $nomor_soal = $rowUsr['nomorsoal'];
                    $jawaban = $rowUsr['jawaban'];
                    $primary = 'btn-primary';
                    $default = 'btn-default';
                    }
                    
                    if ($nomor_soal == $x){
                        ?>
                        <input type="submit" id="btn_nomor" 
name="btn_nomor" style="margin-bottom:4px;" 
class="btn <?php echo $primary; ?>" 
    value="<?php echo $num; ?>"/>
                       <?php
                        }
                    else{
                        ?>
                        <input type="submit" id="btn_nomor" 
name="btn_nomor" style="margin-bottom:4px;" 
class="btn <?php echo $default; ?>" 
    value="<?php echo $num; ?>"/>
                        <?php
                        }
                    }
                ?>
```

**UPDATED**:
Since the variable `$nomor_soal` is outside the *query*, it created **undefined variable**.

I used `empty` to avoid the error and finally, it works as I hoped.

```
                if (empty($nomor_soal)){
                    ?>
                    <input type="submit" id="btn_nomor" 
name="btn_nomor" style="margin-bottom:4px;width:42px;text-align:center;padding:6px 3px;" 
class="btn btn-default" value="<?php echo $num; ?>"/>
                    <?php
                    }
                else{
                    if ($nomor_soal == $x){
                        ?>
                        <input type="submit" id="btn_nomor" name="btn_nomor" 
style="margin-bottom:4px;width:42px;text-align:center;padding:6px 3px;" 
class="btn <?php echo $primary; ?>" value="<?php echo $num; ?>"/>
                       <?php
                        }
                    else{
                        ?>
                        <input type="submit" id="btn_nomor" name="btn_nomor" 
style="margin-bottom:4px;width:42px;text-align:center;padding:6px 3px;" 
class="btn <?php echo $default; ?>" value="<?php echo $num; ?>"/>
                        <?php
                        }
                    }
```

[image]